# What is the Closing event in UWP Page?

Tags: win-universal-app

In WPF, there is a `Closing` event on `<Window...` tag, where we can hook up some dispose code in `MainWindow_OnClosing`.

But there is no such event in UWP app. The closing I guess is `Unloaded`, not even `Unloading` is there.

I just placed my disposing code there but still feel concerned. Is `Unloaded` event supposed for this type of work? Is there something I need to take note?

Comment: Do you want an event for closing the Application or Navigating from the page?

Comment: Just need to dispose my `SpeechRecognizer` on the ViewModel when the window is closed.

Comment: I suppose since there isn't any event present for Application closing. You could use the `Suspending` event to free the resource and acquire it on `Resuming` event.

Comment: Don't use the Suspend and resume events. Those are for different functionality and have an limited time to run before the system shuts the application down. Also, if those events run on the application level and not view-view model one. Check my answer for disposing resources.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect exit for UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693804/how-to-detect-exit-for-uwp)

Answer (score 7):

According to the MSDN, the [Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br209041) class has a [Closed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.window.closed) event.
I'm mentioning this as you posted the `Closing` event of a `window` component, but keep in mind the remark of the event:

> The Closed event occurs when a Window closes. However, Windows Store
>   apps typically use a single Window instance, and do not open and close
>   additional Window instances.

Now, when using the [Frame](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.frame.aspx) navigation system of the main window with [Pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.aspx), I advise you to use the [OnNavigatedTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.onnavigatedto.aspx) and [OnNavigatedFrom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.onnavigatingfrom.aspx) events to manipulate all initialisation and dispose functionality of the class.

You may want to pay attention to the `OnNavigationFrom` as it is invoked immediately before the Page is unloaded and is no longer the current source of a parent Frame.

A really simple example:

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader loader;

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    loader = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader();
    var navigationPageContentFormat = loader.GetString("NavigationPageContent");
    var navigationPageContentWhenEmpty = loader.GetString("NavigationPageContentWhenEmpty");

    this.ParameterTextBlock.Text = String.Format(navigationPageContentFormat, e.Parameter?.ToString() ?? navigationPageContentWhenEmpty);
}

protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    loader = null;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to get called when you close the application with the specific `Page` visible.