# c# - Get when a UWP process exits

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm looking to know how long a process my form started takes until it's closed.

The current implementation looks like this:

```
var p = new Process();
p.StProcess p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = EpFile.FullName; //EpFile is FileInfo
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

p.Exited += (s, e) =>
{
    // Some Stuff
};

p.Start();
```

The problem is this works normally if a normal executable file handles the file given, but if a UWP (In my case Movies & TV) handles the file. the `p.Existed` never fires up, and using `p.WaitForExit()` throws an exception stating that the process is not associated with anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693804/how-to-detect-exit-for-uwp

Comment: @JanMattsson Not really, your example's user is working on a UWP app. I'm working on a WinForms app

Answer (score 0):

Until anyone finds a better answer, I tried a (working) workaround:

```
    public void Open(FileInfo epFile)
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = epFile.FullName;
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        p.Start();

        try
        {
            var h = p.Handle; //Needed to know if the process is UWP
            p.Exited += (s, e) =>
            {
                // Code
            };
        }
        catch
        {
            GetLastWindow().WhenClosed(() =>
            {
                // Code
            });
        }
    }

    private Process GetLastWindow()
        => Process.GetProcesses().OrderBy(GetZOrder).Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.MainWindowTitle)).FirstOrDefault();

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

    const int GW_HWNDPREV = 3;

    private int GetZOrder(Process p)
    {
        IntPtr hWnd = p.MainWindowHandle;
        var z = 0;
        for (var h = hWnd; h != IntPtr.Zero; h = GetWindow(h, GW_HWNDPREV))
            z++;
        return z;
    }
```

With this Extension:

```
    public delegate void action();

    public static void WhenClosed(this Process process, action action)
    {
        var T = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
        T.Elapsed += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (IntPtr.Zero == GetWindow(process.MainWindowHandle, GW_HWNDPREV))
            {
                T.Dispose();
                action();
            }
        };
        T.Start();
    }
```