# Show message dialog when user close application through X

Tags: c#, uwp

How can I display a message dialog when user close UWP application through the X in the upper right corner?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect exit for UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693804/how-to-detect-exit-for-uwp)

Comment: Unfortionatly I can't sem to get it to work

Comment: Where did you stuck?

Comment: I'm trying to read the documentation but can't understand it. Maby my knowledge is lacking but I can't seme to get this to work https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.window.closed?view=winrt-22621#windows-ui-xaml-window-closed

Comment: Be more specific and explain more about your problem ( you may edit the question )

Comment: The **NOT** accepted answer (the one from 2020) from my linked question has everything you need. So where exactly did you get stuck?

Comment: I've got it now, the only problem is that if I click abort in my messageDialog i can't use the button again

Comment: @Daniel Please share the code you are using now so we could check your question.

Answer (score 0):

> the only problem is that if I click abort in my messageDialog i can't
> use the button again

If you want to use the button multiple times in the [ContentDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog?view=winrt-22621#examples), you can create a new ContentDialog with xaml file and add the button in the xaml.

Right-click your project-> Add -> New item -> Select Content Dialog

[image]

**confirmDialog.xaml**

```
<ContentDialog
    x:Class="UWPCloseTest.confirmDialog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:UWPCloseTest"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Tip"
    PrimaryButtonText="OK"
    SecondaryButtonText="Cancel"
    PrimaryButtonClick="ContentDialog_PrimaryButtonClick"
    SecondaryButtonClick="ContentDialog_SecondaryButtonClick">

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="Test Button"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Are you sure you want to close it?"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</ContentDialog>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    Windows.UI.Core.Preview.SystemNavigationManagerPreview.GetForCurrentView().CloseRequested += async (sender, args) =>
    {
        args.Handled = true; // Prevent the default close behavior
    
        confirmDialog confirmDialog = new confirmDialog();
        var result = await confirmDialog.ShowAsync();
       

        if (result == ContentDialogResult.Primary)
        {
            App.Current.Exit(); // Close the app
        }
        
    };
}
```

---

### Update

I optimized my code.

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    var currentview = Windows.UI.Core.Preview.SystemNavigationManagerPreview.GetForCurrentView();
    currentview.CloseRequested += Currentview_CloseRequested;
                   
}

private async void Currentview_CloseRequested(object sender, Windows.UI.Core.Preview.SystemNavigationCloseRequestedPreviewEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true; // Prevent the default close behavior

    
    confirmDialog confirmDlg = new confirmDialog();
    var result = await confirmDlg.ShowAsync();


    if (result == ContentDialogResult.Primary)
    {
        App.Current.Exit(); // Close the app
    }
}
```

Comment: Get error on confirm dialog, i get  CS0118

Comment: Where and when you get the error? Could you please provide more information?

Comment: on the line confirmDialog confirmDialog = new confirmDialog(); and the line after it

Comment: Please check the updates in my answer, I optimized my code. It works fine, if you still get error, please provide the whole error message to help us check the issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it!

```
//Avbryt för att hindra att programmet stängs ned och återgå till föregående text
                message.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Avbryt", x =>
                {
                    e.Handled = true;
                    defferal.Complete();
                }));
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**